# why I could not use <svg> data in WordPress additional css part

Tags: css, svg

I was reading [this article](https://www.svgbackgrounds.com/custom-css-bullets-with-marker/) to customize the bullet lists (**li** tags) in my posts in a WordPress website. But when I want to add these CSS codes:

```
li{
   list-style-image: url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="%23808"><path d="M18 4c-4-1-6 3-6 3s-2-4-6-3-4 6-2 8l8 8 8-8c2-2 2-7-2-8z"></path></svg>');
}
```

in my "WordPress" site in the "Additional CSS" sections in "Customizing" part, I get the error **Markup is not allowed in CSS.** and when I click on publish button, WordPress shows **"Unable to save due to 1 invalid setting."**. Here is the image of that:

[image: additional-css-error image]

I want to know why this is happening and is there any settings or solution for me to be able to add that CSS codes in my website?

Comment: The X inside `list-style-image:url(X)` must be a url, not a html statement

Comment: But the article says that syntax. Is it a limitation in WordPress only? Also Could I change some settings to remove this limitation?

Comment: Yes, it has to do with how WP parses the code. You could try escaping the html, but success is not guaranteed. An example of how to escape this code is here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/url

Comment: You may also want to check out this: https://calendar.perfplanet.com/2020/the-dangers-of-data-uris/